Prevent JSON.net to serialize derived type properties when declared as a base type
Given:
class Mammal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Human : Mammal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Stuff
{
    public Mammal Mammal { get; set; }
}

And
var stuff = new Stuff
{
    Mammal = new Human
    {
        Name = "test",
        Age = 12
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff));

I get:
{"Mammal":{"Name":"test","Age":12}}

But I only want to get properties defined in type statically (meaning that I shouldn't see the name in the JSON), not runtime-type properties. How to do that?

Very unclear what you mean by runtime-type properties - can you please show us what JSON you expect to get from your SerializeObject(stuff) call?

I don't want to see the name property because stuff class was of type of mammal not human.

I agree with marc_s that we're more likely to be able to help you if you were to [edit] your question to add your required JSON for JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff).  Thanks!

Ah, do you mean you want to serialize the value of property as its declared type rather than he actual type of the value, when the actual type is a derived type of the declared type?  If so, that's not dynamic typing, that's polymorphism.  If so, does Using JSON.net, how do I prevent serializing properties of a derived class, when used in a base class context? answer your question?

Alternatively, System.Text.Json works the way you want by default, maybe it would be easier just to use that.

You can try extending DefaultContractResolver:
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        // Of course, the logic here is up to you!
        if (objectType == typeof(Human))
        {
            return base.CreateContract(typeof(Mammal)); 
        }
        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}

It simply says - if the object serialized is of type Human, serialize it accordingly to the contract of the base class Mammal. Which is exactly what you want. This then should be used like this:
var stuff = new Stuff
{
    Mammal = new Human
    {
        Name = "test",
        Age = 12
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    stuff,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() 
    });

Reference: Contract Resolvers

Use [JsonIgnore]:
class Human : Mammal
{
    [JsonIgnore] public string Name { get; set; }
}

This will print:
{"Mammal":{"Age":12}}

